# Real Adjoint representations of complex type

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a semi-simple compact Lie group. Let $V$ be a real vector space and let:

$\rho : G \to Aut_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$

be an irreducible real representation of $G$ on $V$. We say that $\rho$ is a real representation of complex type if and only if there exist a $J\in Aut_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ satisfying:

$J^{2} = - Id\, , \qquad \rho\circ J = J \circ \rho$.

My question is the following: Is there any sort of classification of real irreducible representations of complex type for $G$ compact and semi-simple? I am particularly interested in the case in which $\rho$ is the Adjoint representation of $G$ on its real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that  a simple compact Lie group $G$ is the group of real points of an *absolutely simple* anisotropic algebraic $\mathbb{R}$-group $\bf G$. It follows that the adjoint representation of $G$ is *absolutely irreducible*, and therefore, it cannot be of complex type.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi. Thanks for your comment, that is in fact what I was expecting. Can you please give me a reference to verify your statement?

Comment: This representation is not adjoint.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi. Agreed, I misunderstood your first comment.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi. Does your statement still hold if we consider non-compact simple Lie groups? Thanks.

Comment: No. Take a simple complex group $\bf G$, take $G=R_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}\bf G$, then $G$ is simple, but not absolutely simple, and the adjoint representation of $G$ is of complex type.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi. Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you please explain the notation $R_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}{\bf \mathrm{G}}$ or provide a reference? By a simple complex group ${\bf \mathrm{G}}$ you mean a non-compact real Lie group with compatible complex structure?

Comment: Look at section 6 of Ch. II and section 4 of Ch. VI of the book *Representations of compact Lie groups* by Brocker & tom Dieck. Note that since ${\rm{End}}(V)$ is a finite-dimensional division algebra over $\mathbf{R}$, so it is either $\mathbf{R}$, $\mathbf{C}$, or $\mathbf{H}$, failure to admit a compatible $\mathbf{C}$-action is the same as ${\rm{End}}(V)$ being equal to $\mathbf{R}$, or equivalently (for dimension reasons) that $V_{\mathbf{C}}$ has $G$-endomorphism algebra $\mathbf{C}$. Thus, you seek to classify irreducible $V$ that are *not* absolutely irreducible.

Comment: $R_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}\bf G$ is  Weil's restriction of scalars. This means that you regard a $d$-dimensional complex group as a $2d$-dimensional real group.

Comment: Concerning complex algebraic groups see for example the book by Onishchik and Vinberg.

Comment: As a simple example, consider the 3-dimensional simple complex group $\mathbf{G}=\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, which you can regard as a 6-dimensional simple *real* group $G$. The adjoint representation of $G$ is clearly of complex type. Of course $G$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irreducible *real* representations of *complex* type of a compact group correspond to irreducible complex representations that do not admit an invariant bilinear form. Irreducible real representations of *quaternionic* type correspond to irreducible complex representations that admit an alternating invariant bilinear form. See Serre, Linear representations of finite groups, Section 13.2, Prop. 38.

Concerning invariant bilinear forms on irreducible complex representations of simple groups, see Onishchik and Vinberg, Lie groups and algebraic groups, Table 3 (page 297).

Comment: The OP is using the terminology "complex type" with a meaning different from the usual one (he only asks that $\mathbf{C}$ occur inside the endomorphism algebra over $\mathbf{R}$, not that it coincides; i.e., quaternionic cases are also being called "complex type" by him).

Comment: @nfdc23: Yes, I have noticed this, but he can learn the standard terminology form Serre's book or any other book.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was aware of the terminology, but I wanted to simplify the question so I just defined the complext type to mean both. I will edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\pi$ be a complex representation of the compact connected Lie group $G$
(no need for semisimplicity here) on a (finite-dimensional) vector space $V$. We say that $\pi$ is of *real* type if it comes from a representation of $G$ on a real vector space by extension of scalars, and we say that $\pi$ is of *quaternionic* type if it comes from a representation of G on a quaternionic vector space by restriction of scalars.
If $\pi$ is neither of real type nor of quaternionic type, we say that $\pi$ is of *complex* type.

Let $\rho$ be a real irreducible representation of $G$ on a real vector space
$W$. By Schur’s lemma, the centralizer of $\rho(G)$ in $\mathrm{End}(W)$ is an associative real division algebra, thus, by Frobenius’ theorem, isomorphic to one of (a) $\mathbb R$, (b) $\mathbb H$ or (c) $\mathbb C$.

The relation between real and complex representations is, respectively, that:
(a) the complexification $\rho^c$ is irreducible (and we say that $\rho$ is absolutely irreducible) and $\rho^c = \pi$ is a representation of real type;
(b) the complexification $\rho^c$ is reducible and $\rho^c=\pi\oplus\pi$ where $\pi$ is an irreducible
representation of quaternionic type;
(c) the complexification $\rho^c$ is reducible and $\rho^c=\pi\oplus\pi^*$ where $\pi$ is an irreducible
representation of complex type and $\pi^*$ is not equivalent to $\pi$ (where $\pi^*$ denotes the induced representation on $V^*=\bar V$).

Also $\rho $ is a real form of $\pi$ in the first case ($\rho^c=\pi$), but 
$\rho$ is $\pi$ viewed as a real representation in the other two cases 
($\rho=\pi^r$).

Regarding the adjoint representation of a **compact** simple Lie group, it is always absolutely irreducible. Simplicity of the group is equivalent to irreducibility of the representation. Even in the semisimple case, admiting and invariant complex structure would mean that the Lie group is a complex
Lie group viewed as real, not possible due to the compactness.

Cartan's theory of real representations of semisimple Lie algebras is masterfully presented in modern form in

ESI Lectures in Mathematics and Physics

Arkady L. Onishchik (Yaroslavl State University, Russia)

Lectures on Real Semisimple Lie Algebras and Their Representations
ISBN print 978-3-03719-002-9, ISBN online 978-3-03719-502-4
DOI 10.4171/002
February 2004, 95 pages, softcover, 17 x 24 cm.
24.00 Euro

Comment: Claudio Gorodski can you explain why complexification of the adjoint representation of a compact simple Lie group/algebra is irreducble? I understand that simplicity implies irreducibility of the adjoint representation but I don't see why the complexification is also irreducible which is needed for absolute irreducibility.

Comment: @AdamLeibniz The complexification would be reducible if and only if there is an ad
-invariant complex structure on the (real) Lie algebra of the group. This would mean that the Lie group is a complex Lie group viewed as real. However this is impossible due to compactness of the group.